# what is index calculation?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I read this in Introduction to algorithms book, they didn't want to copy matrix entries because it would take Theta n^2 time and the trick they used was the index calculation and they said,

> In fact, we can partition the matrices without copying entries. The trick is to use index calculations. We identify a submatrix by a range of row indices and a range of column indices of the original matrix. We end up representing a submatrix a little differently from how we represent the original matrix.

I want to know what index calculation is because it's the first step for Strassen's method

Comment: Each element of a 2D-matrix has an index consisting of row and column. Since this is about indexing submatrices, the index calculation for a given matrix element would translate between the indexes of the submatrix and the matrix that contains it. E.g. the submatrix element at (2,3) could be identical to the matrix element at (5,4).

Comment: @njuffa so what is the point of not copying entries if that submatrix is just a matrix contain not all element of the original matrix? That's mean copying some element or I just didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Strassen explains the term in the subsequent lines

"We identify a submatrix by a range of row indices and a range of column indices of original matrix"

So, lets say A = (A11 A12), (A21 A22)  / comma representing new row.

then partition can be represented as
Aij = A, rowrange(..), colrange(...)

```
A11 = A, rowrange(1,n/2), colrange(1, n/2)
A12 = A, rowrange(1, n/2), colrange(n/2, n)
A21 = A, rowrange(n/2, n), colrange(1, n/2)
A22 = A, rowrange(n/2, n), colrange(n/2, n)
```

This partitioning technique, which he calls index calculation, is O(1) compared to copying technique, which he claims it to be O(n^2).